# Push local photos to google photos

Tags: backup, photos, google-photos

Formerly I used Google Photo Uploader to just push my local photos from the laptop to google photos. That's exactly what I need. No syncing etc., only one-way push.

Unfortunately after urging the users to use the new tool "Backup&Sync", Google Photos stopped working completely some days ago.

And now I'm searching for an alternative. Obviously Backup&Sync doesn't support the same feature as Google Photos Uploader.

I didn't manage it to just push the photos. Instead it downloaded several photos again to my local storage.
I don't want this since the local storage holds the images in original resolution while I store them to Google with "high resolution" for unlimited space.

Anyone an idea how I could achieve the old behaviour again? Probably with another tool?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, such an option doesn't currently exist short of uploading manually through the https://photos.google.com/ site.